# An infinite group such that every proper subgroup is finite?

Tags: gr.group-theory

While reading about the Burnside problem, I thought of the following question:

```
 If every proper subgroup of G is finite, does it follow that G is also finite?
```

Despite extensive searching (and thinking), I am unable to find a solution. (I suspect that the answer is no)

Comment: A Google search for the exact quote "every proper subgroup is finite" helps.

Comment: For a finitely generated example see Tarski monster. 

Comment: I'm fairly sure this question or some slight variation had been asked before with the same answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.  The direct limit of the cyclic groups of order $p^n$ is infinite, but every proper subgroup of it is finite.

Comment: I like it.  It is the rotation group of the circle of length 1 by elements of Z[1/2].